# Symfony twig takes 20 second to render

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using symfony 2.6 on mac with built in web server of symfony. Loading pages takes very long time, some times. I checked symfony profiler and and saw that rendering twig is my problem, but i don't know why.

Another thing, when i disconnect my mac from internet, page load speed will be okay (1000ms). What's wrong in my project ?

(i have just 3 external js file in template and test my project with wget but same result)

[image: profiler image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have any external resources in your templates?

Comment: just three js file

Comment: try to comment them and test loading time with enabled internet connection

Comment: i removed them but noting changed ... it's really funny ...

Comment: can you provide that template code

Comment: this issue is in all pages not just one twig file ... i don't know why but also json requests have this issue

Comment: in json calls response time is about 8000 ms

Comment: You have 130 notices and ( I am assuming) 3 errors marked in red in the toolbar, check what they are...

Comment: deprecated and doctrine entity mapping errors ... it has not any effect on response time in this scale ( 20 sec) @JoeYahchouchi

Comment: Do you always develop on this mac? I vaguely remember a few years ago I had some performance issues with the shaky webservers available for mac os, and resorted to using virtualbox with ubuntu instead. It's a long shot and a stab in the dark but... Also, check if page load time differs between the app_dev and the regular production environment, the app_dev with the toolbar usually (I think) has to stop and recheck twig files for changes and log things whereas the prod just uses the twig cache. It could help narrow down the issue.

Comment: i always use it .... but i have issue just with this project (other projects are't symfony - those are laravel in most case) ... i check project on production mod but nothing changed ...

Comment: I would suggest you to try profiling with xhprof. It shows you witch functions take longest time so that you can tear down the problem.

Comment: can you get me some help to do that ? (i will appreciate if share some link) @MaximilianRuta

Comment: xhprof is a php extension you can get from here https://github.com/phacility/xhprof Additional to this you need to put the https://github.com/perftools/xhgui somewhere. In the app.php/app_dev.php you need to enable profiling with xhprof_enable http://php.net/manual/de/book.xhprof.php Which OS runs your project on? For Ubuntu i think there is a third party repository that contains this extension.